# Removing qualifiers with partial template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

To implement an interface that takes a call-back function and a parameter,

*Ex.*

```
template<class T_class_type, class T_data_type>
class Some_interface
{
public:
  Some_interface(T_class_type* inst, void (T_class_type::*func)(T_data_type));
  void add(const T_data_type& data);
private:
  void call(const T_data_type& data);
};
```

where `T_data_type` can be any type and have qualifiers `const` and `&`, I have a problem when the form of is `[T_data_type] = const T_data_type&`. In the function `add()`, for instance, this would expand to, `add(const const T_data_type&& data)`. An obvious compiler error. The reason we pass by constant reference, however, is to reduce unnecessary copying of data. Anyway, to solve this I have implemented the following,

```
template<class T_data_type>
struct No_qualifiers
{
  typedef T_data_type Type;
};

template<class T_data_type>
struct No_qualifiers<T_data_type&>
{
  typedef T_data_type Type;
};

template<class T_data_type>
struct No_qualifiers<const T_data_type>
{
  typedef T_data_type Type;
};

template<class T_data_type>
struct No_qualifiers<const T_data_type&>
{
  typedef T_data_type Type;
};

template<class T_class_type, class T_data_type>
class Some_interface
{
public:
  Some_interface(T_class_type* inst, void (T_class_type::*func)(T_data_type));
  void add(const typename No_qualifiers<T_data_type>::Type& data);
private:
  void call(const T_data_type& data);
};
```

The partial specialization in my tests removes the unwanted qualifiers a user of the interface may have erroneously passed into the template parameter.

Using this in practice, I am finding errors I cannot quite explain. I would appreciate a fresh set of eyes that may be able to see the caveats in this approach.

Some conditions I have is that I cannot change the way users call the interface and I am using an older standard from 2003. The error I'm currently debugging, I believe, stems from `typename` being used in user code as well; possibly passing in an unresolved type into `add()`, which is also unresolved so the compiler cannot find a matching function for the call.

*Edit:*

So the "typename" problem I was having, was a coding error unrelated to the question. In addition, I found removing the `const` specifier was unnecessary, only the `&` needed to be removed.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Where are the semicolons at the end of your class definitions?

Answer (score 1):

The standard already give's you  with [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) and [`std::remove_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) what you're trying to implement yourself; a typedef improves readability:

```
class SomeInterface
{
    using ArgType
        = typename std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
    void add(ArgType const& data);
};
```

To use both with your older compiler, you might just copy the from the "possible implementation" sections – however, I really recommend rather to update to a newer compiler (if available, of course).